# Linuxでのネットワークインターフェースのindexの最大値はどのぐらい?

Tags: linux, network

Linuxのネットワークインターフェースのindex(ip link showで見れるネットワークインターフェースの番号)の最大値はどのぐらいなのでしょうか?
Ubuntu(x86_64)のmanの`if_indextoname`の引数が下のようになっているので、
`(1 << 32)-1`かなと予想しているのですが、実際に定義されているマクロなどは見つけられませんでした。
実際の大きさはどのぐらいなのでしょうか?

```
char *if_indextoname(unsigned int ifindex, char *ifname);
```

Comment: 具体的な数値は分かりませんが、eth0, eth1, ... の形式で表す物理的なインターフェイス名なので、int で表せる範囲なら収まるだろう、ということなのかなと。

Comment: [ここ](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/dev.c#L1175)を見ると、`const int max_netdevices = 8*PAGE_SIZE;` となっていて、手元の環境(x86_64/Linux kernel 5.8.0)では `getconf PAGE_SIZE` の結果が `4096` になりますので、`4096 * 8 = 32768` といったところでしょうか。